# Chrome Extension: Try to read PDF file opened in pop-out window and browser's in-built PDF reader

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

I am working on a Chrome Extension. How can I try to read the PDF that user has clicked opened in browser. This PDF is opened on a button/link click. PDF is either opened in a pop-out window where there is no toolbar and extension visible. Or PDF is opened in site's in-built PDF viewer.

Comment: There's no way to read it.